# How to use += based on outcome of for loop in one statement in python

Tags: python-3.x

When I tried to convert the following code

```
       for item in items:
              page += item.func()
```

to

```
[page += item.func() for item in items]
```

it gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How to achieve this kind of operation in python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use python [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function to achieve what you want:

```py
page += sum([item.func() for item in items])
```

### Extra

I incorrectly assumed you were handling `int`/`float` inputs.
However, depending on the data type you're handling, you might want to use different functions.

For strings, you can use [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20join#str.join):

```py
page += ''.join([item.func() for item in items])
```

For any other type, there might be other functions which are doing this.

### Note

You seem new to Python, please note that doing things in 2 lines is sometimes easier and better than doing it on a single line.

Comment: Technically `page += sum([...])` as we don't know how `page` is defined.

Comment: This solution works for numerical output. I am trying to extract pages.

for e.g.
    `code`
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)

    [pdf_text1 += page.extract_text() for page in pdf.pages]
    `code`

Comment: @HemantSatam You can replace `sum(...)`, with `''.join(...)` for strings

Comment: `''.join([page.extract_text() for page in pages])` like so

Comment: And if you remove the `[`, the code will be much better: no need to generate the list, but only each items, which will be processed by join and sum, one item at a time. (without `[` is takes as you use `(` syntax, so using generators.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do above is list comprehension and you can not assign the values of a list comprehension to any other variable as a new list is being created.

for example if your function 'func' is responsible for squaring a number

```
def func(n):
  return n**2

result=[func(item) for item in items]
```

items=[1,2,3]
results=[1,4,9]

then after getting the result list you can sum all of elemnents in the list by using python's in-built sum() function:

```
page+=sum(result)
```